# Setting up subdomains on localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, subdomain, localhost

I have been trying to set up a subdomain on my local development environment, `dev.localhost`.  I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and Apache2.  So far, I've edited my host file to include the line `127.0.0.1 dev.localhost`.  I've created a file called `axis` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` which looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/Axis/trunk
    ServerName dev.localhost
    ServerAlias *.localhost

    <Directory /var/www/Axis/trunk/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +Includes
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I then enabled the site with `sudo a2ensite axis`. I encountered a no host named error and added the line `ServerName localhost` to my `default` file in `sites-available`.  I also encountered an error that had something to do with `NameVirtualHost`, which I solved by adding `NameVirtualHost *:80` to `httpd.conf` and also commenting it out in `ports.conf`.

Now, when I navigate to `dev.localhost` I get the SAME webpage as I would if I navigated to `localhost`.  In other words, both `localhost` and `dev.localhost` point to `/var/www` but I want `dev.localhost` to point to `/var/www/Axis/trunk`.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?  Thanks

EDIT: output from `apache2ctl -S`

```
ulimit: 88: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
     port 80 namevhost localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
     port 80 namevhost dev.localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/axis:1)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: What was the error?  Can you edit your question to include the output from `apache2ctl -S`?

Comment: There is no error, it just doesn't route to the expected folder.  I posted the results of `apache2ctl -S`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your `/etc/hosts`or `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`(as administrator) to reflect the "subdomain". So add `127.0.0.1  dev.localhost`to either file (depending on your platform).

However it might be that "localhost" as is is somewhat special in terms of a domain name resolution as it might not work as a domain. So instead you can put something like `mylan.local`as server name and `dev.mylan.local` as subdomain. (you can basically use everything you want there)

And in the end, don't forget to reload Apache with `apache2ctl restart` as it needs to reload its config.

Comment: It appears that `localhost` was indeed the problem.  `dev.local` works exactly as expected